# Why doesn't my while loop work if i enter a hidden input

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am currently trying to create a form with a dropdown list that populates itself from a database using a while loop.The form will then submit the user's input into a table in my database.To that end, i am using a while loop with a hidden input to mark the options that are populated in the drop down list, which i will then use to insert into my database.

**PROBLEM:**
My while loop does not loop if i write the code for the hidden input, but it does AFTER i comment out the code for the input.

Excerpt of my code:

```
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head>
<body>
<?PHP //include("AdminNav.php");?>
<form action="<?PHP echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" name="AddSub" method="POST">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Category: </td>
<td>
<select name="category">
<?php
include("cxn.inc");
if($_SESSION['Auth']=="Yes" && $_SESSION['Type']=="Admin")
{
$userid=$_SESSION['UserId'];
$branch="0";
$getcat="SELECT id,Category FROM Categories WHERE Business=$userid && Branch=$branch";
$cat=mysqli_query($cxn,$getcat) or die (mysqli_error($cxn));
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat))
{
    $catid=$row['id'];
    echo"<option value=$row[Category]>$row[Category]</option>";
    //echo"<input type='hidden' name='catid' value='$catid' />";<--This is the line
}

}
else if ($_SESSION['Auth']=="Yes" && $_SESSION['Type']=="Sub")
{
$userid=$_SESSION['UserId'];
$branchquery="SELECT id FROM Branch WHERE Bizid=$userid ";
$getbranch=mysqli_query($cxn,$branchquery) or die(mysqli_error($cxn));
$num=mysqli_num_rows($getbranch);
if($num>0)//Get Branch Details if Branches exist
{
    $resultbranch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getbranch);
    $branch=$resultbranch['id'];
    $getcat="SELECT id,Category FROM Categories WHERE Business=$userid && Branch=$branch";
    $cat=mysqli_query($cxn,$getcat) or die (mysqli_error($cxn));

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat))
    {
        $catid=$row['id'];
        echo"<option value=$row[Category]>$row[Category]</option>";
        //echo"<input type='hidden' name='catid' value='$catid' />";
    }
}
else if($num==0)//Get just the User(Admin) Details if No branches exist
{
    $resultbranch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getbranch);
    $branch=$resultbranch['id'];
    $getcat="SELECT id,Category FROM Categories WHERE Business=$userid";
    $cat=mysqli_query($cxn,$getcat) or die (mysqli_error($cxn));

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat))
    {
        $catid=$row['id'];
        echo"<option value=$row[Category]>$row[Category]</option>";
        //echo"<input type='hidden' name='catid' value='$catid' />";
    }
}

}

?>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SubCategory:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="subcategory" maxlength="50" size="30" required="required" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>

<input type="submit" name="addsub" value="Submit" />
</td>
<td>
<?PHP 
if(isset($success))
{
echo"$success";
}
else if(isset($error))
{
echo"$error";
}   
?> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Extract of my table:

```
 ---------------------------------------------
 |  Id  |  Business  |  Branch  |  Category  |
 ---------------------------------------------
 | 155  |     5      |    0     |    Test1   |
 ---------------------------------------------
 | 156  |     5      |    0     |    Test2   |
 ---------------------------------------------
 | 157  |     5      |    0     |    Test3   |
 ---------------------------------------------
 | 158  |     5      |    0     |    Test4   |
 ---------------------------------------------
```

**Details of problem**

When the line is commented out, the dropdown list populates itself with Test,1,2,3,4 but when i add it in, it only shows Test1.Furthermore, when i test the form(by submitting it) it inserts into the table Branch the Category "Test1" BUT it inserts the id 158(which belongs to category 'Test4'.

Could any kind soul kindly point out my mistake and what i can/should do to correct it? Suggestions to improve my coding would also be most welcome.

Thanks!

**EDIT(SOLUTION)**
Just so anyone else encounters the same issue, What i did was edit a line of code in my processing code for this page from

```
$catid=$row['id'];
```

to

```
 $catid=$_POST['category'];
```

Credits for the solution goes to Corbin

Comment: `input` inside `select` ? you need to correct that buddy

Comment: Is there any way i can work around it? If i put the <input> outside, it doens't register $catid.

Comment: It wont register $catid inside it either as a) input is not valid inside select and b) you are not setting a value for $catid anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't embed a `<input>` inside of a `<select>`.

Just make the `$row['id']` the value of the select. You should probably be working with IDs in the code that handles that form anyway.

Answer (score 5):

`<input>` is not valid in the middle of a select box.

Answer (score 2):

Some more Informations:
Your loop is looping. But you can't see the result in the browser, cause your code is invalid as mantioned in the other answers.

Also check this for "Why is it not secure to use PHP_SELF: http://phpsecurity.wordpress.com/2007/11/03/the-danger-of-php_self/

And you should wrapt your option values in quotes. without them it is invalid, too

I tink that you want to submit the id of the category. this should do it:

```
echo'<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['Category'].'</option>';
```

Comment: Hi Michael, why do you say that i should wrap my option values in quotes, but then say that the quotes are not the problem in response to Tux Dictumst's answer? Would it be because in your example, the PHP_SELF is used in conjunction with htmlentities?

Comment: he changed the quotes of your echo and not the value-attribute of the option-tag. your code is valid, but it generates invalid html-code ;). the hint with the security risk is not relative to your problem. it was just an extra hint ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the echo:

```
echo '<option value='.$row['Category'].'>'.$row['Category'].'</option>';
```

Do the same for the other loop and yes there should be no input inside the select tag.  You can place in outside and do some dom manipulation to change the hidden input value whenever there is a selection